# How to resize an image by DM scripting?

Tags: image, image-resizing, dm-script

### How to resize an image by DM scripting?

When we process an image, we could resize the image by “process – scale -dimensions -width and height, then change the pixels’ number of width or height “ in DM software.

We also have the option “Constrain proportion” when we resize the image.

How to achieve this by scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good question.**

There are a couple of commands you need. `ImageResize()` changes the physical size of an image (i.e. the pixel dimensions) while keeping the meta data (tags) and at the same time changing calibration such that the overall field of view remains the same in calibrated units. However, the pixel values are reset to 0 and need to be re-computed in a second step.

The command `warp()` is used for any mapping with bilinear interpolation of intensity values, so you can use that one for the scaling (plus interpolation).

If you instead want to use "nearest neighbour" interpolation (i.e. copying pixel values), you can most easily achieve this by simple data-copying using the `slice2()` command for sub-sampling or just the [ ] notation of pixel indexing.

As the thing you are asking for is rather a "basic need" in scripting, the answer to it has actually been included in the F1 help documentation's "examples" section in later GMS versions, so I'm just copy-pasting the script here:

[image: Help]

### Example 3: Resizing with intensity interpolation

```
image in, out1, out2
if ( !GetFrontImage( in ) )
 Throw( "No image loaded." )

number sx, sy
GetSize( in, sx, sy )
number f = 1.8        // scaling factor 


// Variant 1, bi-linear interpolation
out1 := ImageClone( in )
ImageResize( out1, 2, sx * f, sy * f )
out1 = Warp( in, icol / f, irow / f )
SetName( out1, GetName( in ) + " bilinear" )
ShowImage( out1 )

// Variant 2, nearest-neighbor interpolation / sampling
out2 := ImageClone( in )
ImageResize( out2, 2, sx * f, sy * f )
out2 = in[ icol / f, irow / f ]
SetName( out2, GetName( in ) + " nn" )
ShowImage( out2 )

// Note: ImageResize() sets all values to zero and 
// adjusts spatial calibration to keep same FOV as before
```

Now, if you want to constrain the aspect ratio, that would be what you need to do in scripting yourself by making sure you use the same sampling factor in X and Y. If you want to mimic *'User enters finals size'* you would do something like this:

```
image in
if ( !GetFrontImage( in ) )
 Throw( "No image loaded." )
     
number sx = ImageGetDimensionSize( in, 0 )
number sy = ImageGetDimensionSize( in, 1 )

string msg = "Please enter wanted X size."
msg += "\n(Currently: " + sx + " pixels)"
number sx_new
if ( !GetNumber( msg, sx, sx_new) ) 
    exit( 0 ) 

number f = sx_new/sx
number sy_new = trunc(sx * f)
Result( "\n New Image size: " + sx_new + " x " + sy_new )
image out1 := ImageClone( in )
ImageResize( out1, 2, sx * f, sy * f )
out1 = Warp( in, icol / f, irow / f )
SetName( out1, GetName( in ) + " scaled" )
ShowImage( out1 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is what I want.  What is your version of DM software? In my DM software,there is only "Tag Types" below the "EXAMPLE SCRIPTS"

Comment: @together Yes, I know. The examples section has been modified/expanded a lot in GMS 3 and the more recent versions. My comment was also not meant to discourage people from asking here - even if the examples are in the help documenation - but to provide the info that there are examples for those who do not know. Personally, I think aksing here on SE is great because it makes the information "Google-able" and public, so please continue doing this whenever you have a question.